# Regex help for password

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

I want to enforce a strong password with the following rules:
- one lowercase char
- one uppercase char
- one number
- one special character

searching through the internet, i came up with this:

`^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[1-9])[a-zA-Z1-9]{8,}$`

but it does not hold up at rubular.com 
some help?

Comment: Personally I would run 4 simple tests, is simpler & that way you can prompt the user with exactly what's wrong with their choice.

Comment: Additionally, I think that e.g. *«this is a wonderful passphrase foo bar»* is more secure and easier to remember than e.g. *«FooBar7@»*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}$
```

**Explanation:**

`(?=.*[a-z])` the password must contain a lowercase letter somewhere.

`(?=.*[A-Z])` the password must contain an uppercase letter somewhere.

`(?=.*[!@#$&*])` the password must contain a symbol somewhere.

`(?=.*[0-9])` the password must contain a digit somewhere.

All of these are look-aheads, meaning each tests for something without actually including it in the match or moving the match position forward.  Thus, after all these tests we are still at the beginning of the string as far as the match is concerned.

`.{8,}` the entire password must contain 8 or more characters. (The `^` and `$` anchor to the beginning and end of the string, so they ensure that the match encompasses the whole string).

The problem with the original was `[a-zA-Z1-9]{8,}`.  This part meant that the entire password had to be made up of eight or more letters and numbers.  This conflicted with the earlier requirement for a special character to be present.  Also, the original did not count zero as a number, which I thought rather silly.

Comment: thats amazing explanation. thank you. will accept the answer in 4 mins. :)